# Iterating Through Text File Only Printing First Line

Tags: python

I am trying to check if the variable 'account' is in a text file (variable 'line'). I iterated through the file and printed out 'line'. Doing so allowed be to print the whole text file. I then added if statement to check if an account is in the file and did a print as well. Only the first line of the text file printed when i used that last 'if' statement.

```
  for account, email,master_name in zip(account_numbers, email_address,master_name):
      fbl_acct_check_q = f"""SELECT * FROM TEST
                             WHERE account_no = '{account.replace("-","")}'"""
      fblacctcursor.execute(fbl_acct_check_q)
      for col_acct_fbl_check in fblacctcursor.fetchall():
                account_status = col_acct_fbl_check[6]
      with open(sumbstatementfilepath) as sbfile:
                lines = sbfile.readlines()
          for line in lines:
              line = line.split()
              print(line)
              if account_status == 4 and account not in line:
                  fbl_account_email()
                  print(line)
                  break
```

Comment: The `break` ends your for-loop, probably that's the problem

Comment: If i remove the break then fbl_account_email gets looped over and over

Comment: Then the if condition is always true, maybe a wrong if-condition? What exactly is `account`? If it is a string you are searching in the line, then leave the `line = line.split()` out.

Comment: Btw, `account_status == 4` always returns the same (`True` or `False`) since it is not changed during the for-loop, so you can check that in advance and only open the file, if `account_status == 4`.

Comment: Great suggestion. I put the account_status == 4 before oepning the file. I found something very weird on why the if condition (if account not in line is always running. I printed the file and it seems that whatever string i am looking for...it erases from the printed file.

Comment: the if account not in line is not suppose to run...because account really is inside the file.